# How to write a loop that calculates p-value for each column against all other columns?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to learn how to use micro array data analysis in R.

I am having trouble in generating p-values for my genes to see which ones are deferentially expressed. I have 22283 rows and 38 columns, of which the rows are probe-sets and the columns are samples, with 18 controls and 19 cases.

How would one generate p-values for each sample (column) against all other samples (columns). So far I have only managed to do cases vs controls.

```
dataset.contols = nz.samples[1,c(1:18)]
dataset.cases = nz.samples[1,c(19:38)]

t.test.probe.1=t.test(dataset.contols,dataset.cases,"two.sided")

#printed p-value for first row
t.test.probe.1$p.value

#gets p-values for all rows,(checked first row p-value with the one
#printed above to ensure consistency)
pvalue.all.probes = apply(nz.samples,1,
                          function(x){t.test(x[1:18],x[19:38]) $p.value})
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Have you looked to [`bioconductor`](http://www.bioconductor.org/) page? The [limma](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) package does almost everything that you need

Comment: I have however my data is not in the correct format for use with this package, I simply have RMA expression signals.

Comment: Sorry, but what does it mean that you have "RMA expression"?
[Here](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/oligo-arrays/) in the sample workflow suggest that you can use limma also for this kind of data.

Comment: Im sorry I am quite new to R. The type of data i have can be seen bellow     Probesets 100 A frontal cortex.CEL 103 A frontal cortex.CEL 106 A frontal cortex.CEL 107 A frontal cortex.CEL
1007_s_at 10.903112 10.604305 9.970952 10.071363
1053_at 6.439545 6.472623 6.484194 6.514294
117_at 7.07203 7.137465 7.562565 7.208024

Comment: The limma analysis can start with a simple matrix, which you have. It doesn't make sense to compare columns -- normalization (your RMA values) have attempted to accommodate differences in absolute intensity, and between-probeset intensity comparisons are intrinsically not meaningful. It's better to ask Bioconductor questions on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/).

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(99), 33))

ps <- data.frame(t(
  combn(ncol(DF), 2, 
        function(ind) c(ind[1], 
                        ind[2], 
                        t.test(DF[, ind[1]],DF[, ind[2]],"two.sided")$p.value))))
names(ps) <- c("col1", "col2", "p")
ps$padj <- p.adjust(ps$p, "fdr")

#  col1 col2         p      padj
#1    1    2 0.4037704 0.7488152
#2    1    3 0.7775216 0.7775216
#3    2    3 0.4992101 0.7488152
```